# Can't bind model in Route::model after upgrade laravel 5.2 to 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, model-binding

This code worked in laravel 5.2 But don't work in laravel 5.3.
I have in `RouteServiceProvider`:

```
\Route::model('users', \App\User::class, function ($value) {
    return User::where('name', $value)
              ->first();
});
```

In my blades I ask for action:

```
'<a href="{{ action('UserController@show',[Auth::user()->name]) }}">{{Auth::user()name}}</a>'
```

And in my `UserController`

```
public function show($user)
{
    return view('users.user.show', compact('user'));
}
```

And now `$user` is only `Auth::user()->name`For example 'qwerty'. But not the object of class User how it has been earlier. What can be a problem?

Comment: Yes, ofcourse Auth::user()->name will only get the name, if you want the object it will be Auth::user()

Comment: You didn't type-hint the model in your controller, how would it know you want the model & not the word 'qwerty' instead? And when you do route binding always try to use a keyword that won't conflict with other things normally ... your 'users' keyword is probably a bad choice

Comment: but it was working in laravel 5.2. I have problem after upgrade to 5.3

Comment: and what is the route?

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that you added:

```
\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
```

to your `web` or/and `api` middleware in `app/Http/Kernel.php` file.

In [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0) you can read:

> Route model binding is now accomplished using middleware. All
>   applications should add the
>   Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings to your web
>   middleware group in your app/Http/Kernel.php file:
>
> \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
>
> You should also register a route middleware for binding substitution
>   in the $routeMiddleware property of your HTTP kernel:
>
> 'bindings' =>
>   \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
>
> Once this route middleware has been registered, you should add it to
>   the api middleware group:
>
> 'api' => [
>       'throttle:60,1',
>       'bindings', ],